# How to populate new value in drop down list after submit button without page refresh in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how to populate drop down list with the new value after submitting the form. I can see the new value only if I do page refresh.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dropdown data source is an Array, just push the new item to the array, that shall be enough.

Comment: Rafaelsr thanks for your suggestion. Now I am able to push new value in to my array. But the thing is that I should push only unique values in to my list. So for that I am trying to iterate through my list and comparing my list with the value entered and then push only if value doesn't exist.
    angular.forEach (List,function(key, value))
    {
       if (List!=value)
       {
         List.push(value);
       }
    }
But it is throwing an error.

Comment: can you share your code? in that snippet is not clear what List is... it is a string Array? object array?